# Como desabilitar horas anteriores da atual com datetimepicke javascript

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Tenho um calendário que funciona corretamente que elimina finais de semana, mas queria também que por exemplo: agora são 11 horas então todos horários anteriores fossem desabilitados para não ser possível selecionar.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $.datetimepicker.setLocale('pt-BR');


    $("#hora").datetimepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dayOfWeekStart: 1,

        addSliderAccess: true,
        sliderAccessArgs: {
            touchonly: false
        },
        format: 'd/m/Y H:i',

        allowTimes: [
            '09:00', '09:30', '10:00',
            '10:30', '11:00', '11:30',
            '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30',
            '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30',
            '17:00', '17:30', '18:00'
        ],
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day != 0 && day != 6)];


        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode te ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860602/datetimepicker-cannot-select-minutes-less-than-current-minute-although-hour-is

Comment: obrigado david    pela ajuda ,mas achei uma solução

Comment: poderia colocar a solução que encontrou como resposta dessa pergunta? Assim se outros usuários tiverem um problema parecido conseguiram resolver o problema.

Comment: sim claro  ja esta abaixo

Answer (score 1):

achei uma solução vou deixar ela aqui na qual e so adicionar um metodo minDateTime: 0

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $.datetimepicker.setLocale('pt-BR');


    $("#hora").datetimepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        minDateTime: 0,

        format: 'd/m/Y H:i',

        allowTimes: [
            '09:00', '09:30', '10:00',
            '10:30', '11:00', '11:30',
            '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30',
            '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30',
            '17:00', '17:30', '18:00'
        ],
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day != 0 && day != 6)];


        }


    });

});
```